# sqsh SQL Server 2005 execute *.sql file

Tags: sql-server, sql-drop, sqsh

I would to drop remote SQL Server db via sqsh but, I don't know how does it works. I can connect to sql server with command:

```
sqsh -Ulogin -Ppass -Smssql2005
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you're connected to the server, you can drop a database with the command

```
drop database [DBName]
```

Assuming that there's no one connected to it, it should work.  And if it doesn't, it'll tell you why.

Comment: main goal of question how to execute sql script via sqsh, but thx for your attention

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'USE table' > script.sqsh
echo 'go' >> script.sqsh
echo 'SELECT * FROM table' >> script.sqsh
echo 'go' >> script.sqsh
sqsh -Ulogin -Ppass -Smssql2005 -i script.sqsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong tool to connect to MS SQL Server. If you are looking to connect to MS SQL Server then you can use this code:

```
SQLCMD -S servername -U username -P password
OR
SQLCMD -S servername -E
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-C` argument lets you specify a query to send to the SQL Server instance.

So, I think this will do what you want:

```
sqsh -Ulogin -Ppass -Smssql2005 -C"DROP DATABASE MyDatabase"
```